# Is this even possible to understand this proof?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, maxwell-equations

Can someone explain what kind of sorcellery is this proof about Maxwell's equations: http://proofs.wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_predict_that_the_speed_of_light_is_constant. Is this a joke?

Comment: Why would it be a joke? And no, it's mathematics not sorcery.

Comment: This is pretty standard fare for a first-semester EM class. It's been a while since I've done vector calculus, but still found the proof pretty straight forward. What steps troubled you?

Comment: I think the interesting point is that $v$ is the same in every inertial reference frame.

Answer (score 7):

The mentioned proof is combining Maxwell's equations in the vacuum together in order to get to a wave equation. The parameter $v$ can be interpreted as a propagation speed, so this shows that the speed of propagation of electromagnetic waves in the vacuum is a "constant".